# How do i get the jqgrid form oper value before submit?

Tags: jqgrid

While i know that jqgrid posts the form oper parameter and value after submit, how do i get the value while in the form?

I need to modify a select field's list contents depending on whether I'm in add or edit form mode.  The only way to do that is to append the oper value to the select dataURL event or dataEvents so i have the correct items in the select list when the form opens.

```
{name:'it.MIID', index:'it.MIID', edittype:'select',
editoptions:{dataUrl:'php/items-se-script.php?data='+jsondata}},
dataEvents:[{type:'what type?',fn:function(e){}}]},
```

It appears the using dataEvents is the way to go but i don't know what type to use?

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do any modification of `editoptions` inside of [beforeInitData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#events) callback of form editing. You can use different `beforeInitData` handler for Add and for Edit forms. Inside of `beforeInitData` handler you can for example set (modify) `dataUrl` so that it includes the additional parameter which you need.